# Why is my regex backreference in R being reversed when I use one backslash with gsub?

Tags: r, regex, gsub, backreference

I do not understand why I am required to use two backslashes to prevent a reversal of my backreference. Below, I detail how I discovered my problem:

I wanted to transform a character that looks like this:

`x <- 53/100 000`

And transform it to look like this:

`53/100000`

Here are a few ideas I had before I came to ask this question:

I thought that I could use the function `gsub` to remove all spaces that occur after the `/` character. However, I thought that a regex solution might be more elegant/efficient.

At first, I didn't know how to backreference in regex, so I tried this:

`> gsub("/.+\\s",".+",x)
[1] "53.+000"`

Then I read that you can backreference captured patterns using `\1` from [this website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html). So I began to use this:

`> gsub("/.+\\s","\1",x)
[1] "53\001000"`

Then I realized that the backreference only considers the wildcard match. But I wanted to keep the `/` character. So I added it back in:

`> gsub("/.+\\s","/\1",x)
[1] "53/\001000"`

I then tried a bunch of other things, but I fixed it by adding an extra backslash and enclosing my wildcard in parentheses:

`> gsub("/(.+)\\s","/\\1",x)
[1] "53/100000"`

Moreover, I was able to remove the `/` character from my replacement by inserting the left parenthesis at the beginning of the pattern:

`> gsub("(/.+)\\s","\\1",x)
[1] "53/100000"`

Hm, so it seemed two things were required: parentheses and an extra backslash. The parentheses I understand I think, because I believe the parentheses indicate what is the part of text that you are backreferencing.

*What I do not understand is why two backslashes are required.* From [the reference website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) it is said that only `\l` is required. What's going on here? Why is my backreference being reversed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra backslash is required so that R doesn't parse the "\1" as an escape character before passing it to gsub. "\\1" is read as the regex \1 by gsub.

Comment: I understand now. I must have been very unfortunate because "\1" is rendered as "\001" by gsub, and my pattern was "100". Thank you for answering.